# Identify the pattern to get desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have below table contains multiple code against the ID and CounterID. Need an output based on code and id.

Condition: Against the ID and CounterID

case 1 : if there is code CI and CO then no record

case 2 : if there is code CI and CO and CI then last record with code CI

case 3 : if there is code CI then last CI

[image]

Thanks
Rahul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytical function as follows:

```
select t.* from
(select t.*, row_number() over (partition by sno order by date desc) as rn,
       count(case when code = 'CI' then 1 end) over (partition by sno) as cicount,
       count(case when code = 'CO' then 1 end) over (partition by sno) as cocount 
from your_table t) t
where ( (cocount = 0)
       or not (cicount = 1 and cocount  = 1) 
       or (cocount > cicount ))
  and rn = 1
```

Comment: Hello Popeye, where clause need to change.
where ( (cocount  = 0 and cicount = 1)
       --or not (cicount = cocount ) 
    or ( cicount > cocount ))
  and rn = 1

Comment: Hello Popeye, We can also do in where clause : and rn = 1 and  code='CI'  to get the last CI..

Comment: Yeah, actually requirement was difficult to be answered quickly. :) please adjust the wher clause according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic simplifies to:  The last row when it has `'CI'`.  One method with window functions is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1 and code = 'CI';
```

You can also do this without window functions:

```
select t.*
from t
where code = 'CI' and
      date = (select max(t2.date) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```